# Guidance to set up metrics for a service using istio

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio

I was wondering if anyone could point me to a good source for getting a service using istio to report basic metrics. I would assume that simple things like response successes (200), errors (503,404, etc), transaction time would be automatically wired up but I am guessing I am missing something.

I have used things like collectd and statsd to aggregate metrics in the past but was expecting some basic things to be wired up automatically.

I plan to play with the bookinfo app soon to see if perhaps this answers my questionsL https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to setup the [Bookinfo](https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/) sample application then I would recommend sticking to istio documentation.

If you go into [ISTIO / DOCS / TASKS / TELEMETRY / METRICS / COLLECTING METRICS](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/telemetry/metrics/collecting-metrics/) it will explain how to setup basic metrics collection via the Prometheus UI using Mixer functionality.

> The metrics configuration directs Mixer to send metric values to Prometheus. It uses three stanzas (or blocks) of configuration: *instance* configuration, *handler* configuration, and *rule* configuration.
>
> The `kind: instance` stanza of configuration defines a schema for generated metric values (or *instances*) for a new metric named `doublerequestcount`. This instance configuration tells Mixer *how* to generate metric values for any given request, based on the attributes reported by Envoy (and generated by Mixer itself).
>
> The `kind: handler` stanza of configuration defines a *handler* named `doublehandler`. The handler `spec` configures how the Prometheus adapter code translates received metric instances into Prometheus-formatted values that can be processed by a Prometheus backend. This configuration specified a new Prometheus metric named `double_request_count`. The Prometheus adapter prepends the `istio_` namespace to all metric names, therefore this metric will show up in Prometheus as `istio_double_request_count`. The metric has three labels matching the dimensions configured for `doublerequestcount` instances.
>
> The `kind: rule` stanza of configuration defines a new *rule* named `doubleprom`. The rule directs Mixer to send all `doublerequestcount` instances to the `doublehandler` handler. Because there is no `match` clause in the rule, and because the rule is in the configured default configuration namespace (`istio-system`), the rule is executed for all requests in the mesh.

Also you can read and setup [Querying Metrics from Prometheus](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/telemetry/metrics/querying-metrics/) using Prometheus add-on:

> Mixer comes with a built-in [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) adapter that exposes an endpoint serving generated metric values. The Prometheus add-on is a Prometheus server that comes preconfigured to scrape Mixer endpoints to collect the exposed metrics. It provides a mechanism for persistent storage and querying of Istio metrics.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I expected to see some basic things like request successes and failure code counts aggregated by service and/or route and was assuming I was missing some meta setting to enable this.